How to save to the local database when offline and automatically sync when connected to the internet in Realm and React Native?
I'm trying to implement a flexible online and offline application with Realm, but I followed their documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/device-sdks/sdk/react-native/sync-data/configure-a-synced-realm/#std-label-react-native-open-a-synced-realm
However, when I disable my internet and open the app, trying to save a document offline, it gives me this error:
ERROR  [error] App: request location failed (CustomError -1): request to https://realm.mongodb.com/api
My RealmWrapper:
import { RealmProvider, useApp } from '@realm/react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { ActivityIndicator, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import 'react-native-get-random-values'
import { Realm } from 'realm'
import App from './App'
import { SupplierSchema } from '@database/schemas/supplierSchema'

function RealmWrapper (): JSX.Element {
  const app = useApp()
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(true)
  const realmAccessBehavior: Realm.OpenRealmBehaviorConfiguration = {
    type: Realm.OpenRealmBehaviorType.OpenImmediately
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const login = async () => {
      try {
        const credentials = Realm.Credentials.anonymous()
        await app.logIn(credentials)
        setIsLoggedIn(true)
      } catch (error: any) {
        if (error.message.includes('Network request failed')) {
          setIsLoggedIn(false)
        } else {
          console.error('Erro de login:', error)
        }
      }
    }
    login()
  }, [app])

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <RealmProvider
          schema={[SupplierSchema]}
            sync={{
              flexible: true,
              newRealmFileBehavior: realmAccessBehavior,
              existingRealmFileBehavior: realmAccessBehavior
            }}
        >
          <App />
        </RealmProvider>
      ) : (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default RealmWrapper

I am performing the query within the component:
  const realConn = useRealm()

Write:
  const createNewSupplier = useCallback(() => {
    realConn.write(() => {
      void realConn.create<ISupplier>('supplier', {
        convert: supplierInfo.convert,
        createdAt: new Date().toDateString() as unknown as Date,
        factory: supplierInfo.factory,
        flag: supplierInfo.flag,
        mesh: supplierInfo.mesh,
        name: supplierInfo.name,
        others: supplierInfo.others,
        tinCode: supplierInfo.tinCode,
        trading: supplierInfo.trading
      })
    })
  }, [realConn])

My Schema:
import { createRealmContext } from '@realm/react'
import { type SupplierModel } from 'models/supplier.model'
import Realm from 'realm'

export type ISupplier = Omit<SupplierModel, 'id'>
export class SupplierSchema extends Realm.Object<ISupplier> implements ISupplier {
  public name!: string
  public tinCode!: string
  public trading!: boolean
  public convert!: boolean
  public factory!: boolean
  public flag!: boolean
  public mesh!: boolean
  public others!: boolean

  public static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
    name: 'supplier',
    properties: {
      _id: {
        type: 'objectId',
        default: () => new Realm.BSON.ObjectId()
      },
      name: 'string',
      tinCode: 'string',
      trading: 'bool',
      mesh: 'bool',
      convert: 'bool',
      factory: 'bool',
      flag: 'bool',
      others: 'bool',
      createdAt: {
        type: 'string',
        default: () => new Date().toISOString()
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: 'string',
        default: () => new Date().toISOString(),
        optional: true
      }
    },
    primaryKey: '_id'
  }
}

const RealmSupplierContext = createRealmContext({
  schema: [SupplierSchema]
})

export const useRealmSupplier = () => RealmSupplierContext

